# Django - model not defined

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to add a new form to my Django project, but i keep getting this error:

```
cannot import name 'SomeModel' from 'main.models'
```

I don't get why, since i defined `SomeModel` in my **models** file. Here is my code:

```
from .models import SomeModel
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from captcha.fields import CaptchaField
from django.forms import ModelForm

class TestForm(ModelForm):

    data = forms.CharField(label='Data', max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = ("test",)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        send = super(TestForm, self).save(commit=False)
        send.data = self.cleaned_data['Data']
        if commit:
            send.save()
        return send
```

And here is my model:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    data = forms.CharField(max_length=100)

    def save(self): # ALL the signature
        super(SomeModel, self).save(using='dataset')
```

**Edit:** **forms.py** and **models.py** are in the same folder (project->main->**forms.py, models.py**!

What am i doing wrong? Am i not declaring my model properly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: would you mind to share your project structure as well?

Comment: You should not be using `forms.CharField` in your model; use `models.CharField` instead.

Comment: And yes, we also would like to know the project structure to see if the relative import is correct. If your 2 files (`models.py` and `forms.py`) are side by side, then your code should work...

Comment: Yes! forms.py and models.py are in the same folder

Comment: are you under some virtualenv? what python version is used? please share your project structure!

Comment: No i'm not on any virtualenv and it's Py 3.7. I edited my post adding the structure

Comment: @Jack022 I see that `class TestForm` is indented differently than the other lines before that (the import lines). Is it like that in your code?

Comment: @Ralf I'm sorry, it's an error i did when writing the question

Comment: @Jack022 according to the model you posted, `fields = ("test",)` is not a valid field; it appears there is only one field called `data`. You would need to change that for the form to work.

Comment: @Ralf so i should change 'test' to be 'data' instead?

Comment: @Jack022 yes, because that is the name of your field. By the way, you don't need to redefine the field in your form (you can, but you dont have to; you can remove the line `data = forms.CharField(label='Data', max_length=100)`) because the ModelForm will pull all the info it needs directly from the model.

Comment: @Ralf Ok, so i removed the line you mentioned but i keep getting the import error ' cannot import name 'SomeModel' from 'main.models'

Comment: Please post the traceback you get with the error, also import statements you use in your model file.